# Set routes in method using router class in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter for one of my project. I can easily setup routes like this for using custom routes

```
$routes['users'] = 'home/getuser/';
```

But i want to setup this route when getuser is called. Have a look on example below

```
function getuser() {
    $this->router->routes('users/(:num)', 'home/getuser/$1');
    redirect(base_url().'users/'.12);
}
```

so this route will only be called whenever this method will be called. How is this possible ? How can i implement routing like in this way in codeigniter ?

Comment: So no explanation about this?

Comment: is this `$this->router->routes()` an actual function or just to explain what you are trying to accomplish? i believe all routes have to be set in the routes  config file. there are some ways around it but its hacky.

Comment: can you explain some of the cases how can i achieve what i have explained above?

Comment: i've only ever seen something like this (doesn't apply directly to your case): https://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter. since it is just one function i wouldn't even bother trying to implement something like this. is it possible? probably with a lot of trial and error and messing around with the internals. i would design around it knowing that basically if it isn't defined in routes.php you can't really change it on the fly.

Comment: you also have to consider that the primary reason why this won't work is the same reason why you can't set config variables on the fly. the second the page reloads (or redirects) it isn't stored unless by session or cookie. so this route would immediately disappear. you'd quite literally have to write it the route file and then remove it (which would affect all users - not just the one that went to `getuser`). so in short, again, don't try - design around.

Answer (score 0):

`$routes['users'] = 'home/getuser/';` 
is it `$routes`?

codeigniter use this : `$route['users'] = 'home/getuser/';`

and also: `$route['users/(:num)'] = 'home/getuser/$1';`

Comment: i know this kind of declaration already, please have a look on question again.